# In clipping border mode, sculpt tool has no effect, help is much appreciated

Tags: sculpting

When working in in clipping border mode (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>) I cannot use sculpt tool on certain objects. If I deactivat it again, it works.

Through elimination of other objects on the layer I figured out that an empty (center) object was the problem.

Why does this happen? And if I need the empty object what should I do to prevent?

[image]

[foot.blend.zip](https://blenderartists.org/uploads/default/original/4X/0/0/7/007d2d9e2ee6c6cc6245e8f77fb11cfb3abb90d4.zip)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off **X-Ray** on the empty.

However, you should [report it to the bugtracker](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/).